# How do I stack multiple Switches?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm currently testing running 2 or more switches, however I'm having issues with how they prioritise themselves. For example -

```
switch (Scanner Input) 
    {
      case 1:
        System.out.print("Example");
         break;
      case 2:
         get.example();
         break;
    }
switch (Scanner Input2) 
    {
      case 1:
        System.out.print("Example");
         break;
      case 2:
         get.example();
         break;
    }
```

If I was to run this, it would ask for both of my inputs and THEN does prints out/runs method. Instead of switch 1 > runs outcome > switch 2 > runs outcome. Also if there is a fix, is it possible to do it in a loop?

Hopefully this makes some kind of sense, I'm still new so my terminology is off. Thanks massively in advance!

Comment: I'm having a really hard time trying to understand what you want it to do. Care to explain further or include all code. Expected output etc?

Comment: Sorry if it was poorly explained. Basically I just want a way of running it in this order.. Switch 1 > Output Results > Switch 2 > Output results etc. 

As of now it goes Switch 1 > Switch 2 > Switch 1 Results > Switch 2 results. I'll add the full code if this still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by moving your switch logic to another method and then invoke it if it is meant to do the same, so you don't write it twice, here a piece of code that can help you and that's how I think you want to do this, I added some messages to the user there.
I removed the breaks in the cases because I'm using return, so it would be unreachable code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pregunta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press 0 to exit.");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        while ( input != 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( switchUsersInput(input));
            System.out.println("Press 0 to exit.");
            input = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Finish.");
    }



    public static String switchUsersInput( int input )
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                return "Example";
            case 2:
                return "Example 2 I didn't get your get.example();";
            default:
                return "Chose something :)";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot, and well explained :)

Comment: Glad to know that, try to think always in writing your logic once, and call it from wherever you need

Comment: Yeah I've made the same mistake multiple times with other aspects of Java, and only just started using methods/classes, thanks again for your help